# Installed successfully; home page still redirects to install.php

Tags: installation

I've done WP installs in the past and haven't had issues, so I'm a little stumped here.

I've correctly created wp-config.php. I ran the install script, and everything appeared to be successful. I have all the tables in MySQL and am able to log into the dashboard with the admin account I created.

However, the home page is still redirected to install.php. Clicking the button to install brings up a message that WP is already installed (which is what I would expect to see), but the home page doesn't want to load the blog.

I can, however, open the test post that comes with the install just fine. It's only the home page that isn't working.

If it helps any, this is an installation I've set up for a project on Sourceforge.

Comment: Start by checking your file permissions and make sure that you have at least one theme installed.

Answer (score 1):

Try repairing the `wp_options` table, that solved the issue for me months ago. 
Also make sure the table prefix in wp-config.php is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Please clean your browser cache and try it again!
Worked for me.

Comment: Way to necro a four year old thread, bro.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this: in wp-admin delete/rename install.php